# Modifying the date index of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I am trying to write a highly efficient function that would take an average size dataframe (~5000 rows) and return a dataframe with column of the latest year  (and same index) such that for each date index of the original dataframe the month containing that date is between some pre-specified start date (st_d) and end date (end_d). I wrote a code where the year is decremented till the month for a particular dateindex is within the desired range. However, it is really slow. For the dataframe with only 366 entries it takes ~0.2s. I need to make it at least an order of magnitude faster so that I can repeatedly apply it to tens of thousands of dataframes. I would very much appreciate any suggestions for this.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
from pandas.tseries.offsets import MonthEnd

def year_replace(st_d, end_d, x):

    tmp = time.perf_counter()

    def prior_year(d):
        # 100 is number of the years back, more than enough.
        for i_t in range(100):

            #The month should have been fully seen in one of the data years.
            t_start = pd.to_datetime(str(d.month) + '/' + str(end_d.year - i_t), format="%m/%Y")
            t_end = t_start + MonthEnd(1)
            if t_start <= end_d and t_start >= st_d and t_end <= end_d and t_end >= st_d:
                break
        if i_t < 99:
            return t_start.year
        else:
            raise BadDataException("Not enough data for Gradient Boosted tree.")

    output = pd.Series(index = x.index, data = x.index.map(lambda tt: prior_year(tt)), name = 'year')

    print("time for single dataframe replacement = ", time.perf_counter() - tmp)    

    return output


i = pd.date_range('01-01-2019', '01-01-2020')
x = pd.DataFrame(index = i, data=np.full(len(i), 0))

st_d = pd.to_datetime('01/2016', format="%m/%Y")
end_d = pd.to_datetime('01/2018', format="%m/%Y")
year_replace(st_d, end_d, x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice is: avoid loop whenever you can and check out if an easier way is available.

If I do understand what you aim to do is:

> For given `start` and `stop` timestamps, find the latest (higher) timestamp `t` where month is given from index and `start <= t <= stop`

I believe this can be formalized as follow (I kept your function signature for conveniance):

```
def f(start, stop, x):
    assert start < stop
    tmp = time.perf_counter()
    def y(d):
        # Check current year:
        if start <= d.replace(day=1, year=stop.year) <= stop:
            return stop.year
        # Check previous year:
        if start <= d.replace(day=1, year=stop.year-1) <= stop:
            return stop.year-1
        # Otherwise fail:
        raise TypeError("Ooops")
    # Apply to index:
    df = pd.Series(index=x.index, data=x.index.map(lambda t: y(t)), name='year')
    print("Tick: ", time.perf_counter() - tmp) 
    return df
```

It seems to execute faster as requested (almost two decades, we should benchmark to be sure, eg.: with `timeit`):

```
Tick:  0.004744200000004639
```

There is no need to iterate, you can just check current and previous year. If it fails, it cannot exist a timestamp fulfilling your requirements.

If the day must be kept, then just remove the `day=1` in `replace` method. If you require cut criteria not being equal then modify inequalities accordingly. The following function:

```
def y(d):
    if start < d.replace(year=stop.year) < stop:
        return stop.year
    if start < d.replace(year=stop.year-1) < stop:
        return stop.year-1
    raise TypeError("Ooops")
```

Returns the same dataframe as yours.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Why is looping a problem as it is an incomplete loop which should break pretty fast without going into a full loop?

Comment: Loop are not bad, they are necessary unless there is a quicker/easier way to solve your problem. In fact I would have compress the code with a `for i in range(2)` because there are two cases two check. You should check Zen of Python (`import this`) for more insight on it, mainly readability and flatness.

Comment: I believe what is taking time in your case is date casting from string and time arithmetic. I avoided it because I used replace which is quite faster.

Comment: Thanks. When I replaced `pd.to_datetime(str(d.month) + '/' + str(end_d.year - i_t), format="%m/%Y")` with `d.replace(year = end_d.year - i_t)` it became as fast as your code. But you are right of course that in this case it was not meaningul to write a loop.

Comment: You are welcome, so you found the bottleneck of your code. Feel free to mark this post as answer. Cheers.